# Skype Crashes with a Segmentation fault

Tags: skype

Under 13.04, Skype is crashing with a seg fault.

```
$ skype
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
$
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Though the first comment seemed to do the trick. Thanks Brandon!

Comment: ! By the way, this is part of the release notes. You can add that the bug affected you: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/skype/+bug/1155327.

Comment: For Skype, see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/skype/+bug/1155327 . It is written in the release notes.

Comment: a fix has been released by ubuntu

Comment: That's a tricky issue related to the memory allocation bugs in either glib, Qt or Skype.
https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=698716 Temporary solution would be to either use LD_PRELOAD technique or downgrade glib or build glib with `-Wall`.

Answer (score 37):

You can also do the following way ...

```
sudo nano /etc/ld.so.conf.d/skype.conf
```

copy and paste the following line in it

```
 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/
```

and then run

```
 sudo ldconfig -v
```

This issue was mentioned in the [release notes](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDUQFjAA&url=https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RaringRingtail/ReleaseNotes&ei=JCV_UZSoHKq7ygGm84HIDA&usg=AFQjCNHsH64Gg8bn8HmlihSw8rxKVznxRw&sig2=tVMt4nZM7Z0orogD-T9EJg&bvm=bv.45645796,d.aWc&cad=rja).

- [Bug #1155327 “skype crashed with SIGSEGV in malloc@plt()” : Bugs : “skype” package : Ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/skype/+bug/1155327)

Comment: Note that this breaks Steam for Linux. If you want to use steam, you need to remove this .conf file or rename it to something that does not end in `.conf`. Then run `ldconfig` and run Steam.

Comment: @Chris ty for updating ......

Comment: This is applicable for ubuntu 14.04 as well. I had the same issue in HP envy - 64 Bit. After run above command the skype loaded without any issues.

Answer (score 6):

Temporary workaround. Open a terminal and paste this in:

```
sudo  mv /usr/bin/skype{,-bin}
sudo install -b -m 744 <(<<EOF
#!/bin/sh
export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1
exec /usr/bin/skype-bin
EOF) /usr/bin/skype
```

Then Skype should

Comment: Weird, why does skype need mesa libs?

Answer (score 4):

1. To get Skype to work in Ubuntu 13.04 Raring Ringtail with proprietary Nvidia / AMD drivers, firstly we'll rename the Skype executable from "skype" to "skype-bin":

   `sudo mv /usr/bin/skype /usr/bin/skype-bin`
2. Now let's create a file called "skype" under /usr/bin/ - for this we'll launch a text editor as root (I'll use Gedit in the instructions below):

   `gksu gksu gedit /usr/bin/skype`

(I've used "gksu" twice in the command above so Gedit doesn't open a blank tab along with /usr/bin/skype)

And in this file, paste the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1
exec skype-bin "$@"
```

Then save the file.

1. And finally, run the following command in a terminal:

   `sudo chmod 0755 /usr/bin/skype`

That's it. Now Skype should work in Ubuntu 13.04 Raring Ringtail.

If you want to revert the changes made by using the instructions above, use these commands:

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/skype
sudo mv /usr/bin/skype-bin /usr/bin/skype
```

[source](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/fix-skype-not-working-in-ubuntu-1304.html)

Comment: Thank you so much Blade, but , How I can fix the another errors?

Comment: @AlphaPolaris to fix pidgin contact list bug. http://askubuntu.com/questions/67286/pidgin-doesnt-show-buddy-list, and  about the compiz fusion not showing in the status bar - `the Unity systray whitelist has been removed,` meaning it cannot be displayed there anymore. see: http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/ubuntu-1304-raring-ringtail-final-beta.html

Comment: For future references, please ask a question per post, or try to search for your question before posting.

Answer (score 1):

If you, like me, have Skype installed before upgrading Ubuntu 12.10 to 13.04, uninstall it. Go to Ubuntu Software Center, find Skype and Uninstall.

Add the Ubuntu Partners repository, in Ubuntu Sofware Center, Edit Software Origins, add the following repository:

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ raring partner
```

Close Sofware Center, then update repository info, from a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Open Sofware Center again, find and install Skype. You will note that an additional package called Indicator Support for Qt is marked, let it in that way.