# Can't figure out how to install "humble double fine bundle"

Tags: 13.04, games

I just bought the Humble Double Fine Bundle  and downloaded the .bin file, and it says it uses the mojo installer.

When I'm trying to open the installer I get this error:

```
jeggy@jeggy-XPS:~/Niðurtøkur$ sudo ./CostumeQuest-Linux-2013-05-07-setup.bin
./CostumeQuest-Linux-2013-05-07-setup.bin: error while loading shared libraries: libbz2.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I googled and I found this:
[image]
And that looks just like my problem, but the link is dead now :/

I am running Ubuntu 13.04 64bit

**EDIT:**

It says I have libbz2-1.0 installed

```
jeggy@jeggy-XPS:~/Niðurtøkur$ sudo apt-get install libbz2-1.0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libbz2-1.0 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

ldd:

```
jeggy@jeggy-XPS:~/Niðurtøkur$ ldd ./CostumeQuest-Linux-2013-05-07-setup.bin
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf77a9000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0xf7769000)
libbz2.so.1 => not found
libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0xf7763000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xf7720000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xf756d000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf77aa000)




jeggy@jeggy-XPS:~$  sudo find / -name libbz2.so.1
[sudo] password for jeggy: 
/home/jeggy/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1
```

It took very long until I got response from that command.

Comment: Please update your question with the output of `ldd ./CostumeQuest-Linux-2013-05-07-setup.bin` (as the output should be lengthy use some paste service like paste.ubuntu.com).

Comment: In case you wanted that link: [here it is](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?client=ubuntu&hs=ayu&hl=en&channel=fs&biw=959&bih=678&sclient=psy-ab&q=cache%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Faskubuntu.com%2Fquestions%2F292334%2Fdouble-fine-humble-bundle-installation-problems-13-04&oq=cache%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Faskubuntu.com%2Fquestions%2F292334%2Fdouble-fine-humble-bundle-installation-problems-13-04&gs_l=serp.3...69691.118420.0.119293.102.53.0.0.0.1.283.3572.2j17j5.24.0...0.29...1c.1.12.psy-ab.hcLcbL5svoc&pbx=1)

Comment: sudo find / -name libbz2.so.1 > it took me about 7.47 secs , if you want speed you should have an SSD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple Way To Fix The Error

```
 sudo find / -name libbz2.so.1
```

The Output is

```
 /var/cache/lxc/centos/x86_64/6/rootfs/lib64/libbz2.so.1
 /var/cache/lxc/raring/rootfs-amd64/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1
 /var/lib/lxc/centos/rootfs/lib64/libbz2.so.1
 /var/lib/lxc/container/rootfs/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1
 /var/lib/lxc/juju/rootfs/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1
 /var/lib/lxc/client/rootfs/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1
 /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1
```

Then Simply You Need To Load This Lib libbz2.so.1 Before Executing

For 32 bit app

```
 LD_PRELOAD=/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1 ./CostumeQuest-Linux-2013-05-07-setup.bin
```

If that work Then simple Check the this answer [Skype Crashes with a Segmentation fault](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285642/skype-crashes-with-a-segmentation-fault/285916#285916)

### OR

```
  sudo ln -s /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1 /usr/lib32/
  sudo ldconfig -v
```

Then Run The Setup

---

### Update

Make a file

```
 sudo gedit /etc/ld.so.conf.d/hib.conf
```

Copy paste the following line in it

```
 /home/jeggy/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/lib/i386-linux-gnu/
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
 /lib/i386-linux-gnu/
```

Save & exit & then run the following command

```
  sudo ldconfig -v
```

Lastly run the setup

```
 sudo ./CostumeQuest-Linux-2013-05-07-setup.bin
```

---

#### Solved With Google + Screen Sharing

```
 sudo cp /home/jeggy/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1.0.4 /usr/lib/libbz2.so.1

 sudo ldconfig -v
```

Lastly run the setup

```
 sudo ./CostumeQuest-Linux-2013-05-07-setup.bin
```

Comment: the second one didn't work, and i updated the question with the output of the first one, it looks like it has something to do with Steam.

Comment: @Jeggy please check the update ........

Comment: I followed your update and got the same error :/ hib.conf was empty, don't know if it was supposed to be empty.

Comment: have you copy pasted /home/jeggy/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/lib/i386-linux-gnu/
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
 /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ these line init ?

Comment: @Jeggy do you have skype ? so i can figure out what you are doing

Comment: @Jeggy So it works now?

Comment: @Seth yes its working ...last screen was start up menu of the game ..google screen sharing

Comment: Yes it's working, just followed the "Solved With Google + Screen Sharing" by Qasim and it will work, if anyone else gets this problem also

Answer (score 0):

You can install libbz2 like this

```
sudo apt-get install libbz2-1.0
```

Comment: I updated the question with my output with that command

Comment: The bin file which you downloaded is for 64bit version only?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libbz2-1.0:i386` should do it if you are using 64bit assuming you are right about the library file, you could just install [ia32-libs](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/ia32-libs)

Answer (score 0):

Try finding where the `libbz2.so` are installed to and make a symlink/copy to `libbz2.so.1`. It's usually in `/usr/lib/` if I recall correctly.

IMPORTANT: To anyone trying this, make sure to remove the library afterwards. This kind of fiddling is supposed to be only for debugging/workaround, not a permanent solution.

Comment: I believe they ll be picked up automatically if they are in /usr/lib.

Comment: I looked in /usr/lib and it isn't there :/

Comment: I just looked at my Ubuntu machine, and found the libraries in these location: `/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1`, `/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1.0.4`, `/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1.0`, `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1`, `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1.0.4`, `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1.0`.

Comment: However, check out the other suggestions about installing the 32-bit version of the library since it seems the installer is a 32-bit only binary. Those seems like a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you look in the /usr/lib**32** folder to create the symlink (and of the library in that folder, not from the lib folder as that is 64bit).

The installer seems to be 32 bit (obvious when you look at the output of ldd).
After creating an extra symlink to libbz2.so.1 in the lib32 folder it installed fine. (although it did spam some more exception messages)

Comment: Hohum, 32bit is actually not installed by default so you'll have to install it... (sudo apt-get install lib32bz2-1.0) (I'm still on 10.04, but I rechecked with a newer version)

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal, use `cd` to navigate to download directory. Type:

```
chmod u+x *filename*
```

Hit enter then type:

```
./*filename*
```

Additional details: this works on Ubuntu 13.04 x64, and I simply typed the file names WITH NO EXTENSIONS (i.e. no .bin etc.)

This should open the installation prompt in the terminal.

Comment: i tried that, but it didn't work for me. see the accepted answer to see what i needed to do to fix the problem