# Could not find required OpenGL entry point 'glGetError'

Tags: steam, opengl

I am not able to play "Half-Life-2" on Steam + Ubuntu 14.04 .
Error shown in message box on screen:

```
    Could not find required OpenGL entry pint 'glGetError'! Either your video card is unsupported, or your OpenGL driver needs to be updated.
```

I have a Dell Inspiron Laptop. 
My OS is Ubuntu 14.04 and my graphics card is AMD Radeon HD 8600M. 
I have installed AMD properietry Driver.

The partial output of "glxinfo" is as follows:

```
    name of display: :0
    libGL: screen 0 does not appear to be DRI3 capable
    libGL: pci id for fd 4: 8086:0a16, driver i965
    libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/tls/i965_dri.so
    libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so
    libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/arushi/.drirc: No such file or directory.
    libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
    libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
    libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so
    libGL: driver does not expose __driDriverGetExtensions_swrast(): /usr/lib/i386- linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so: undefined symbol: __driDriverGetExtensions_swrast
    libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/arushi/.drirc: No such file or directory.
    libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/arushi/.drirc: No such file or directory.
    libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
    display: :0  screen: 0
    direct rendering: No (If you want to find out why, try setting LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a lot of internet searches I have found the solution to this problem.

Please read the comment made on the [SteamCommunity](http://steamcommunity.com/app/221410/discussions/1/882966056488160497/?l=english#p2) forum by Christian Günther.

I just followed these steps and rebooted the system:

```
sudo rm /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.2.0
sudo ln -s /usr/lib32/fglrx/fglrx-libGL.so.1.2 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0
```

Now Half Life is working properly on my system..!

Comment: Good to see that it was use full to write my solution down. :)

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution to my problem. To get TF2 to work again all I had to do was remove the symbolic link that I made to get Skype working:

> /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1

The problem now is Skype doesn't work again. I guess I'll just have to remake the symbolic link whenever I want to use Skype until Canonical fixes the seg fault issue with Skype.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old thread but removing / deleting this symlink is not a great answer at all. Many other applications depend on this file, although steam requires current drivers.

Please read my solution to this issue:

[Ubuntu 14.04 “could not find required OpenGL entry point 'glGetError'!"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/539858/ubuntu-14-04-could-not-find-required-opengl-entry-point-glgeterror/592692#592692)

Comment: This was a workaround for a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/skype/+bug/1155327?comments=all) on Canonical's end that has since been fixed. This shouldn't be relevant anymore.

Comment: Weird then. Because I had this issue 4 days ago? Great fix from their end then..