# Ubuntu 14.04 “could not find required OpenGL entry point 'glGetError'!"

Tags: 14.04, drivers, opengl

I am trying to play Dota2 and FT2 on my pc when I got this error:

> "Could not find OpenGL entry point 'GLGetError'! Either your video
>   card is unsupported or it needs to be updated."

I have spent the last week reading all of the similar questions and have tried some of them (many solutions were to advanced for me to try so I stayed away from them) and I do not know what else to do. If there is any other information needed just ask.

I am using:

- Ubuntu 14.04 32 bit
- GLX version is 1.4
- OpenGL version string: 1.4 Mesa 10.1.3
- `00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 82G33/G31 Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 10) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])`

-

```
libgl1-mesa-glx:<br>
  Installed: 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.1<br>
  Candidate: 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.1<br>
  Version table:<br>
 *** 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.1 0<br>
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main i386 Packages<br>
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status<br>
     10.1.0-4ubuntu5 0<br>
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main i386 Packages
```

Comment: Check this out. It worked for me http://askubuntu.com/questions/506349/opengl-glx-context-is-not-using-direct-rendering-which-may-cause-performance-pr

Answer (score 5):

OK! FINALLY. After hours and hours trying to figure out what is going on I got my steam fixed.

Follow these steps and you will be fine.
The reason is that steam is trying to use "mesa" drivers and not my ATI Radeon drivers.
Stupid steam.

Now:

1. First close steam.
2. Then open `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/steam.conf` for editing:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/ld.so.conf.d/steam.conf
   ```
3. In the editor add these two lines:

   ```
   /usr/lib32
   /usr/lib32/fglrx/
   ```
4. Finally run:

   ```
   sudo ldconfig
   ```

Open Steam. Voila.

I rate if you wish to use the mesa drivers you just have to replace the last line with something like this:

```
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa
```

And sorry I don't know what the directories are for GeForce cards but go check in that `/usr/lib32` folder for the driver folder for your card and update it where you can locate the `libGL.so.1` file. this is what Steam is looking for.

Hope this helps someone else.

This was a fix on Ubuntu 14.04 64bit with Radeon drivers.

Comment: Still no luck with Nvidia. There's `/usr/lib32/nvidia-332` folder which I pointed in `steam.conf` without results.

Comment: @s3m3n wish I could help you out more. My solution is for Radeon drivers I only assumed that the Nvidia drivers would work the same way. Thanks for letting me know :)