# Could not find required OpenGL entry point 'glGetError' ethier your video card is unsuported or you need to update open GL.

Tags: steam, opengl

Could not find required OpenGL entry point 'glGetError' ethier your video card is unsuported or you need to  update open GL. this pops up when i try to open tf2 through steam. I am not using a video card but I am using  amd a10 richland APU please help for i am a complete noob on linux. running ubuntu 14.10 
also, when i open steam i get a message saying I don't have direct rendering, i looked at some forums and dont under stand. thanks.

THANK YOU FOR YOUR HELP

Answer (score 0):

I posted an answer/fix in this thread
[Ubuntu 14.04 “could not find required OpenGL entry point 'glGetError'!"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/539858/ubuntu-14-04-could-not-find-required-opengl-entry-point-glgeterror/592692#592692)

that relates to steam games and the openGL entry point issue.

note to you: use the "/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa" instead of the "/usr/lib32/fglrx/"

Also make sure you have the latest mesa drivers installed.