# Could not find OpenGL entry point 'glGetError'

Tags: drivers, 15.04, intel

I recently downloaded steam and purchased team fortress 2 and Garry's mod on Ubuntu 15.04. And it came up with the error

```
Could not find required OpenGL entry point 'glGetError'! Either your video card is unsupported, or your OpenGL drivers need to be updated.
```

PC Specs:

```
Memory: 1.9GB
Processor:Intel Pentium Dual CPU E2180 2.00Ghz x 2
Graphics: Intel G33
OS Type: 64 Bit
Disk: 243.8GB
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Could not find required OpenGL entry point 'glGetError'](http://askubuntu.com/questions/475756/could-not-find-required-opengl-entry-point-glgeterror)