# Steam will not run games (OpenGL Error)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, games, steam, opengl

Every time I go to play a game on Steam it won't run, and gives me this error:
Could not find required OpenGL entry point 'glGetError'! either your video card is unsupported, or OpenGL driver needs to be updated. However I know for a fact that my graphics card has been updated, and I have tried countless answerers, but none of them have worked. (I have a Nvidia GTX 970)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Could not find required OpenGL entry point 'glGetError'](http://askubuntu.com/questions/475756/could-not-find-required-opengl-entry-point-glgeterror)

Answer (score 1):

run these commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

if you get an error, run this command instead:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0
```

then, run the following commands and reboot:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "/usr/lib32\n/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa\n" >> /etc/ld.so.conf.d/steam.conf' && sudo ldconfig
```

[source](http://steamcommunity.com/app/221410/discussions/1/882966056488160497/?l=english#c846939071329672205)