# How do I uninstall the mesa drivers now I've switched my graphics to nvidia?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, ati, opengl, mesa

As per [Why-are-my-32bit-opengl-libraries-pointing-to-mesa-instead-of-nvidia](https://askubuntu.com/questions/313173/why-are-my-32bit-opengl-libraries-pointing-to-mesa-instead-of-nvidia-and-how-do/683095), I've managed to get ldconfig to no longer reference mesa drivers by editing the conf files, but when the mesa GL drivers get upgraded, they come back. If I try to uninstall them, I get this:

```
/etc/ld.so.conf.d$ sudo apt-get remove --purge libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-glx 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libqt5feedback5 : Depends: libqt5multimedia5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt5quick5 : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.2.0) but it is not going to be installed
 phonon : Depends: phonon-backend-gstreamer1.0 but it is not going to be installed or
                   phonon-backend
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Is there a right way to remove these drivers?