# Skype crash immediatly after launch

Tags: skype, gtk

when I'm launch skype, it crashes immediatly.

Error:

```
mathieu@mathieu-desktop:~$ skype
`menu_proxy_module_load': skype: undefined symbol: menu_proxy_module_load

(skype:10442): Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to load type module: (null)

`menu_proxy_module_load': skype: undefined symbol: menu_proxy_module_load

(skype:10442): Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to load type module: (null)

`menu_proxy_module_load': skype: undefined symbol: menu_proxy_module_load

(skype:10442): Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to load type module: (null)

`menu_proxy_module_load': skype: undefined symbol: menu_proxy_module_load

(skype:10442): Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to load type module: (null)

Abandon (core dumped)
mathieu@mathieu-desktop:~$
```

Can you help me?

Thank.

Comment: Are you using any proprietary driver?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/285642/skype-crashes-with-a-segmentation-fault/285916#285916

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error.

In my case it depended to xorg.conf

I have a NvidiaCard inside my Laptop, and for another program i created the xorg.conf - file through the Button "Save to X Configuration File".

To this time everything worked fine, but after this Skype crash after the launch. So I deleted the File (xorg-conf).

Now Skype works normally, there is also the same failure - Message in the Terminal but it runs.