# Program unable to find libGL.so.1

Tags: 12.04, installation, gnome, games

this involves the game Hotline Miami which I bought from the Humble Bundle 8 a while ago.

After installing it and clicking the executable nothing happened so I ran it from the terminal and got this error:

```
/opt/hotline-miami/hotline_launcher: error while loading shared libraries: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

But I do appear to have libGL.so.1 installed according to the locate command which gives me this:

```
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/primus/libGL.so.1
/usr/lib/nvidia-current-updates/libGL.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/primus/libGL.so.1
/usr/lib32/nvidia-current-updates/libGL.so.1
```

Any idea on what is causing this problem? I wasn't able to find any solution online.

Computer is an Acer 4830TG running Ubuntu 12.04
(This game worked on 12.10 perfectly fine before I had decided to switch to 12.04)

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/285642/skype-crashes-with-a-segmentation-fault/285916#285916

Comment: @Qasim I tried your answer in that link to the question you posted but I still get the error I posted above.

Comment: sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 /lib32/ && sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 /lib64/ && sudo ldconfig -v

Comment: Ok I tried it again but replaced it with the 64 bit libraries but now I get error while loading shared libraries: libGL.so.1: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64, I looked up the solution for it but that didn't work and i still get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that if I uninstall ia32-libs and the packages that depended on it the game will run though there is the issue of no sound currently.

Comment: Could you add instructions on which specific libraries and how exactly you removed them to your answer in order to help future users? Thanks.

Comment: ok, I added which libraries I had removed.