# Skype doesn't launch after NVIDIA driver installation

Tags: 13.04, drivers, nvidia, xorg, skype

I just installed NVIDEA drivers and found that Skype doesn't launch. I tried several solutions that I found here (like [that](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285642/skype-crashes-with-a-segmentation-fault)), but no one helped.

So, that's what I see if I try to launch Skype from terminal:

```
$ skype 
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/libv4l/v4l1compat.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded: ignored.
/usr/bin/skype: error while loading shared libraries: libGL.so.1: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
```

And my `xorg.conf`:

```
Section "Screen"
Identifier "Default Screen"
DefaultDepth 24
EndSection  

Section "Device"
Identifier "Default Device"
Driver "nvidia"
Option "NoLogo" "True"
Option "GLShaderDiskCache" "True"
EndSection

Section "Module"
Load "glx"
EndSection
```

Can you help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this help:

[launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/skype/+bug/1002187](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/skype/+bug/1002187/comments/48)

This person find a solution for that problem